# flash google maps api directions failure 400

Tags: flash, google-maps, map-directions

I created a map with the Google
Map API For Flash that shows directions. It creates a line between the
2 addresses and gives turnbyturn directions.

This is working perfectly in Flash test mode locally but once i put it
online The map still works but the directions dont show and i get the
Failure status 400.

Does anywone know whats the problem here? I'ts driving me crazy just
because **its working locally but not online**.

```
DirectionsEvent.DIRECTIONS_FAILURE.feature.status = 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
Dir.load("New York to Los Angeles");
```

working locally but not online

```
Dir.load("from: New York to: Los Angeles");
```

working both

Answer (score 0):

Google turned off Google Maps API for Flash... http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/09/maps-api-for-flash-deprecation.html.  Sorry...

Comment: no, it's not, https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api-for-flash/browse_thread/thread/f6c3f9631b7e4ae5/6589a0df6218e01d
same problem from Jan 2010,
and this too
http://osdir.com/ml/google-maps-api-for-flash/2010-01/msg00123.html